Unable to Filter Decimal128 Field in MongoDB with Django, But Can Filter Integer and String Fields
I'm working on a Django project using MongoDB as my database. I have a Product model with a Decimal128 field for storing product prices. I'm trying to filter products based on price, but I'm encountering issues when attempting to filter using the Decimal128 field.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
class FilterProducts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            category = request.GET.get("category")
            min_prices = request.GET.get("min_price")
            max_price = request.GET.get("max_price")

            all_products = Product.objects.all()

            if category:
                all_products = all_products.filter(category=category)

            if min_prices:
                all_products = all_products.filter(price__gte=min_prices)
                print(min_prices)

            if max_price:
                all_products = all_products.filter(price__lte=max_price)

            response = [
                {
                    "title": product.name,
                    "category": product.category,
                    "price": product.price.to_decimal(),
                    "description": product.description,
                }
                for product in all_products
            ]

            return JsonResponse(response, status=200, safe=False)

        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(str(e), status=400)

Below is the Model created for Product:
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shipping = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

The Issue:

When I try to filter the Decimal128 price field, no results are returned, even when I know that matching data exists.
Filtering based on integer or string fields works perfectly fine like Category.
I've tried converting the price filter value to Decimal128 and Decimal, but it still doesn't seem to work.

What I've Tried:

Ensured the price data is stored as Decimal128 in MongoDB.
Used Decimal128(Decimal(value)) to create the filter value.
Double-checked the precision of the decimal values to ensure they match the stored values.

Questions:

Is there something specific about filtering Decimal128 fields in MongoDB that I'm missing?
How can I correctly filter products based on a Decimal128 price field using Django and MongoDB?
Is there a better approach or workaround to handle this filtering issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The Custom Type example from the docs does this for Decimal128 <--> Decimal. You'll need to modify the validator/output for Django's DecimalField type.
